# How do I partially share param values across union selects using different constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a view

```
create or replace view v_collected as
  select car.id_car
        ,car.state_car
        ,[..]
   from cars    car
       ,garages garage
       ,[..]
  where [..]
```

Which is at least unique for `car.id`

Now I want to union 3 different queries into a second view, which takes user set parameters:

```
select 0 as score
      ,p0.*
 from v_collected p0
where 1 = 1
  -- User IO Binding
  and p0.car       = 'Audi'
  and p0.garage    = 'P01'
  and p0.state_car = 'Ok'

union

select 1 as score
      ,p1.*
 from v_collected p1
where 1 = 1
  -- Should access the identical binding
  and p1.car       <> p0.car
  and p1.state_car =  p0.state_car
union

select 2 as score
      ,p2.*
 from v_collected p2
where 1 = 1
  -- Should access the identical binding
  and p2.state_car =  p0.state_car
```

The above does not work as the 2nd query has no access to the the 1st one. As the constraints change, I believe I cannot use a CTE. What are my options?

Comment: **I believe I cannot use a CTE** Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the requirements are vague, I can't say for sure that the following solution is complete, however, I would look into breaking the p0, p1, p2 into with clause sub queries that way you can use p0 in p1 and p2.  For example:

```
with cars as
(
select 2 id_car, 'Ford' car, 'Ok' state_car from dual union
select 1 id_car, 'Audi' car, 'Ok' state_car from dual
)
, garages as
(
select 2 id_car, 'P02' garage from dual union
select 1 id_car, 'P01' garage from dual
)
, v_collected as
(
select car.id_car
      ,car.car
      ,car.state_car
      ,garage.garage 
from cars    car
    ,garages garage
where 1=1
  and car.id_car = garage.id_car
)
-- select * from v_collected; 
, p0_subquery as
(
select 0 as score
      ,p0.*
 from v_collected p0
where 1 = 1
  -- User IO Binding
  and p0.car       = 'Audi'
  and p0.garage    = 'P01'
  and p0.state_car = 'Ok'
)
--select * from p0_subquery;
, p1_subquery as
(
select 1 as score
      ,p1.*
 from v_collected p1
 , p0_subquery p0
where 1 = 1
  -- Should access the identical binding
  and p1.car       <> p0.car
  and p1.state_car =  p0.state_car
)
, p2_subquery as
(
select 2 as score
      ,p2.*
from v_collected p2
, p0_subquery p0
where 1 = 1
  -- Should access the identical binding
  and p2.state_car =  p0.state_car
)
select * from p0_subquery
union
select * from p1_subquery
union
select * from p2_subquery
;
```